# How to remove the last character from a multiline string?

Tags: java, string, multilinestring

**Example:**
*Consider a String like below:*

```
String a="This line1 has a,b,c,\nThis line2 has d,e,f, \nThis line3 has g,h,i";
System.out.println(a);
```

**Output:**

```
This line1 has a,b,c,                 
This line2 has d,e,f,                        
This line3 has g,h,i
```

As this is a multiline string, How will I be able to remove last occurring comma of each line here from the output & print an output like below below mentioned?

```
This line1 has a,b,c                
This line2 has d,e,f                        
This line3 has g,h,i
```

Comment: `Arrays.stream(a.split("\n"))
        .map(l -> l.replaceAll("(.*?),\\s*$", "$1"))
        .forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a regex:

```
String output = a.replaceAll(",\\s*\n", "\n");
```

It will replace any sequence of a comma, 0 or more spaces and a newline with just a newline character.